# Сравнение соседних объектов в массиве и их слияние

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть непонимание работы с переберающими свойствами массивов в javascript.
У меня есть исходный массив, допустим, вот такой:

```
const arr = [
{text: 'stack', color: 'yellow', fontSize: '30px'},
{text: 'over', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'},
{text: 'flow', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'}
]`
```

И я хочу из него получить массив со следующими объектами:

```
const newArr = [
    {text: 'stack', color: 'yellow', fontSize: '30px'},
    {text: 'overflow', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'}
    ]
```

Т.е. я пытаюсь сравнить объекты по ключам color и fontSize и если они совпадают - объединить текст и удалить ненужный объект.
Пробовал решить через старый добрый for:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (arr[i].fontSize === arr[i + 1].fontSize && arr[i].color === arr[i + 1].color) {
           arr[i].text = arr[i].text + arr[i + 1].text;
           finalArr.push(arr[i]);
         } else {
           finalArr.push(arr[i+1]);
         }
       }
```

Но цикл работает неверно, невозможно обработать последний объект массива. Да и хотелось бы узнать, как можно это решить с использованием ES6 синтаксиса.

Comment: `< arr.length -1` позволит обработать последний объект

Comment: что ты понимаешь под _ES6 синтаксисом_?

Comment: Т.е. при помощи методов filter/reduce/etc. С ними решение будет более элегантным

Answer (score 0):

Для ваших задач простой цикл вполне подходит, так что я предложил вариант и с ним. Но если хотите использовать методы массивов (многие из них появились уже в ES5), можно попробовать `reduce()` (поскольку вам нужен массив с другим количеством элементов и элементы нужно менять, `map()` и `filter()` не очень подходят по назначению — хотя, наверное, можно ухитриться и с ними). Из совсем новых методов можно использовать `flatMap()`, хотя это, пожалуй, не самый очевидный вариант.

```js
const arr = [
  {text: 'stack', color: 'yellow', fontSize: '30px'},
  {text: 'over', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'flow', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'stack', color: 'black', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'over', color: 'green', fontSize: '30px'},
  {text: 'flow', color: 'green', fontSize: '30px'},
];

const finalArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const current = arr[i];
  const next = arr[i + 1];
  if (next && current.fontSize === next.fontSize && current.color === next.color) {
    next.text = current.text + next.text;
  } else {
    finalArr.push(current);
  }
}

console.log(finalArr);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {text: 'stack', color: 'yellow', fontSize: '30px'},
  {text: 'over', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'flow', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'stack', color: 'black', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'over', color: 'green', fontSize: '30px'},
  {text: 'flow', color: 'green', fontSize: '30px'},
];

const finalArr = arr.reduce(
  (acc, current, i, array) => {
    const next = array[i + 1];
    if (next && current.fontSize === next.fontSize && current.color === next.color) {
      next.text = current.text + next.text;
    } else {
      acc.push(current);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [],
);

console.log(finalArr);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {text: 'stack', color: 'yellow', fontSize: '30px'},
  {text: 'over', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'flow', color: 'red', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'stack', color: 'black', fontSize: '14px'},
  {text: 'over', color: 'green', fontSize: '30px'},
  {text: 'flow', color: 'green', fontSize: '30px'},
];

const finalArr = arr.flatMap(
  (current, i, array) => {
    const next = array[i + 1];
    if (next && current.fontSize === next.fontSize && current.color === next.color) {
      next.text = current.text + next.text;
      return [];
    } else {
      return current;
    }
  }
);

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ и примеры :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно пойти таким путем. Он конечно изменяет исходный массив, но это легко исправить предварительно скопировав его.

```
const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, obj, index) => {
  arr.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if( obj && el && index !== idx && obj.color == el.color && obj.fontSize == el.fontSize ){
      obj.text += el.text;
      arr[idx] = null;
    }
  });
  if(obj) acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Смотрел в сторону reduce, но не понимал как его тут можно применить